# Post to a friends wall

Tags: c#, facebook, asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-mvc-4

I have an `MVC4` application that uses `OAuth` to login via facebook. Once logged in the user can then choose a guestlist from their Facebook Friends. This is fine as I am managing to retrieve the facebook Friends and their ID's.

Now I want to be able to post to the Friends wall a message from the application. Is this possible at th moment as there seems to have been a lot of changes to what Facebook allows you to do, if a wall post is not possible, can a private message be sent?

I have no code snippets from this one, just direction would be appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have used  this code for posting on friend wall

```
var fbApplication = new DefaultFacebookApplication { AppId = fbapp, AppSecret = fbsec };
            var current = new FacebookWebContext(fbApplication);

            Facebook.Web.FacebookWebClient client = new Facebook.Web.FacebookWebClient(token);
            //client.AccessToken = current.AccessToken;   
            dynamic parameters = new ExpandoObject();
            parameters.message = "";
            parameters.link = link;
            parameters.name = name;
            parameters.caption = caption;
            parameters.description = desc;
            parameters.from = fromId;//your fb ID
//friendId will be the ID of the person,you wants to post on wall
            object resTest = client.Post("/" + friendId + "/feed", parameters);
```

Alternatively you can use Graph API's feed dialog

[check this](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/dialogs/feed/)

Comment: what is DefaultFacebookApplication? Is there a dll you need to download

Comment: yes, you need to install Facebook Package from VS libraray Package  manager